# Angular 5 - How to properly set up posts for website

Tags: angular

I'm learning angular and trying to build a personal website with it as well as firebase. I'm trying to figure out the best approach for making posts on the webpage. Should I make each post a component? I want to be able to keep the posts unique, but similar formatting style.

Another idea is to put the posts in the firebase backend: have a posts collection, and a document for each post that has similar fields.

I would like to be able to modify the javascript of each post individually in case I want to get creative. Have been doing some research on my own but thought I'd ask those who have more experience with Angular.

Comment: check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ5z9SFBlek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do create the following for showing the posts:

- post-list-component
- post-component
- service post
- post

**post** : class representing the post you want to store in firebase

**post-service** : service handling the communication with backend/firebase

**post-list-component** :view component that asks the post-service for all post and then iterate over the response populating a list of post-components

**post-component** : View component styled for the post you fetched from firebase and iterate over in post-list-component.

And if you want different handling of different posts you can implement dynamic component loader. Here is a good example:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Perfect, i was reading up on services, but was a bit unsure how to go about implementing it with  my desired goal. thanks for the resources!